# Decoding NumPy int64 binary representation

Tags: python, sqlite, numpy, sqlalchemy

So I did a stupid thing, and forgot to explicitly type-convert some values I was putting into an SQLite database (using Python's SQLalchemy). The column was set up to store an `INT`, whereas the input was actually a `numpy.int64` dtype.

The values I am getting back out of the database look like:

`b'\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

It seems that SQLite has gone and stored the binary representation for these values, rather than the integer itself.

Is there a way to decode these values in Python, or am I stuck with loading all my data again (not a trivial exercise at this point)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`struct.unpack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

```
>>> import struct
>>> value = struct.unpack('<q', b'\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
>>> value
(21,)
>>> value[0]
21
```

That assumes that the data was stored little endian as specified by the `<` in the `unpack()` format string, and that it is a signed "long long" (8 bytes) as specified by the `q`. If the data is big endian:

```
>>> struct.unpack('>q', b'\x15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
(1513209474796486656,)
```

I imagine that little endian is more likely to be correct in this case.

P.S. I have just confirmed that when a `numpy.int64` is inserted into a SQLite `int` field it can be retrieved using `struct.unpack()` as shown above.

Comment: Thank you, that works a charm. The data was indeed little endian.